# dispatch.fcgi and ruby on rails using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fastcgi

I'm trying to just get a "hello world" application working on my hosting service (Dreamhost) using **rvm**.  I'm using **rvm** so that I can use Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1

I recognize there are better hosting environments and better ways to do this, but for now I thought I'd try to struggle through and try to make this work.

I have a cgi script working that shows rvm seems to be working ok:  http://rails.hortitude.com/foo.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/hortitude/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p290

puts "Content-Type: text/html"
puts
puts "<html>"
puts "<body>"
puts "<h1>Hello Ruby!</h1>"
puts "<p>shebang: #!/usr/bin/env /home/hortitude/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p290</p>"
puts "<p>RUBY_VERSION: " + RUBY_VERSION + "</p>"
puts "<p>RUBY_PLATFORM: " + RUBY_PLATFORM + "</p>"
puts "<p> RUBY_RELEASE_DATE: " + RUBY_RELEASE_DATE + "</p>"
puts "</body>"
puts "</html>"
puts "</html>"
```

However, my dispatch.fcgi script always gives me an error (found in the error logs)

> Premature end of script headers: dispatch.fcgi

Here's my dispatch.fcgi script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/hortitude/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p290

ENV['GEM_HOME'] ||= '/home/hortitude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290'

require 'rubygems'
require 'fcgi'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

# Set GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME ("user" is your dreamhost user)
##ENV['GEM_HOME'] ||= '/home/user/.gems'

require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths


require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment')

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
 def initialize(app)
   @app = app
 end

 def call(env)
   env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
   parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
   env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
   env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
   @app.call(env)
 end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run  Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(Helloworld::Application)
```

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend against using FCGI to run Ruby code of any kind.  Use [passenger](http://www.modrails.com) if you need to run within Apache or use a Rack server such as Thin, Unicorn, or Mongrel.

Comment: Yea -- the only reason using FCGI here is that AFAIK it is the only way to have rails 3.1 on dreamhost.   Once I get things to my liking I was going to switch things off to a different rails host for my project.  At the moment I just feel like it is a solvable problem, so wanted to see it through.

Comment: Dreamhost claim to support passenger (http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger)

Comment: dreamhost supports passenger, just not for rails 3

Comment: Is there any particular reason for having two `puts "</html>"` lines at the end of your CGI script?

Comment: that was just a mistake.  No need to have second </html>

Comment: I've just found, also on DreamHost, that when I use your foo.cgi script (the only change being to replace your username with mine), it works fine when called `foo.cgi` but causes a 500 Internal Server Error when named `foo.fcgi`. This is really weird, but I think it may also explain why your dispatch.fcgi is failing. Think I might contact DreamHost for support.

Comment: This difference persists despite the fact that the `.fcgi` script [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/106067/how-do-i-setup-apache-with-fastcgi-and-ruby) works fine.

Comment: It remains true even if I create a `.htaccess` file as described here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails_3#Using_FastCGI

Comment: Hm, OK, maybe it's not so weird, in that if I've got the fcgi gem installed where ~/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p290 can find it, and if I then wrap the `puts ...` lines of your `foo.cgi` script in `require 'fcgi'; FCGI.each_cgi do` and `end`, then it works when named `foo.fcgi`.

Comment: Let me know if you still aren't able to get this fully working.  I've debugged this a couple times now.

Comment: Got it working OK on Ruby 1.9.2-p290, but not yet out of the woods with 1.9.3-p194. Did you figure out how to stop getting the `Premature end of script headers: dispatch.fcgi` messages in your error.log?

Comment: Same issue, never resolved. If you run 'dispatch.fcgi' directly in console, you would find it returns nothing. That's why soap he complains that error.
Same happened in any applications build with rails 3, even hello world. And it is not only on Dreamhost, but also on my own server.